# Ajax calls stop working while using MVC Custom routes

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I have defined custom routes for user friendly URLs.

But unable to call default route using ajax or on using `Ajax.BeginForm()` On removing custom routes, all works perfectly.

This is my RouteConfig.cs

```
 //product view route
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ProductView",
                url: "product/{product_name}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Product", action = "View", product_name = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "NoveltyApp.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "NoveltyApp.Controllers" }
            );
```

Product View URL: http://localhost:56379/product/Camlin-Kokuyo-Acrylic-Color-Box---9ml-Tubes-1/1

ProductController.cs

```
 public string ProductReviews()
 {
    return "Product review list";
 }
```

Ajax call from Product view

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-thm nf-pr-vi__btn" onclick="reviews()">Reviews</button>

<script>
function reviews() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/ProductReviews',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

But on click button controller action not getting hit. Please help me out with a solution.

Comment: where is routevalues which is contain the route parameter?

Comment: There no route values for ProductReviews action. It should work using default route.